# Call Macro if conditions are met

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to run a script that will run if both of the below conditions are met, however the macro does not run. What am I missing?

```
Dim Answer As VbMsgBoxResult

If Sheet9.Range("H6").Value = "True" And Sheet9.Range("L5").Value = "Err" Then

Answer = MsgBox("Error: The Macro needs to be run before closing workbook ")

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: If you don't get a `MsgBox` then either one or both of the conditions are false. Use `Debug.Print`: `Debug.Print Sheet9.Range("H6").Value = "True"`, `Debug.Print Sheet9.Range("L5").Value = "Err"`.

Comment: What macro are you talking about? Do you imagine that sending a message a specific macro will hear and execute by itself?  If you need to validate a message, in order to, let us say, take a decision, the way you try is incomplete. You only used the `prompt` parameter. It must be followed by, let us say `vbYesNo` making the message  window to show to buttons. The you must be check what  button has been pressed: `If Answer = vbYes Then runMyMacro`. When you say "Call macro if conditions are met", do you only want  to make the message appearing? Are you sure that the initial conditions are True?

Comment: "the macro does not run" - how are you running it?

Comment: I believe the issue is that Sheet9.Range("L5").Value = "Err" is False, but should be true. Err is returned through a function - could that be the issue? I'm stepping through the code with F8, but ultimately the code will be triggered before Workbook save

Comment: Is the cell value literally "Err", or an actual error value? Maybe you need something like `IsError(Sheet9.Range("L5").Value)`

Comment: It is literally Err, like the function returns "Err". I figured that one out with debug.print, need to change it to Sheet9.Range("L5").Value = "Err" in order to become true. Sheet9.Range("H6").Value = "True" appears to be the issue since it returns FALSE in the immediate window when debug.print. True is being returned when a checkbox is checked..I can't explain though why it is happening I'm using the same script in another part of the workbook and it works fine.

Comment: The value `"True"` is a string literal. Have you tried the value `True` (a `Boolean` literal) instead?

Comment: Is this code meant to be run manually or is it triggered by an event?

Comment: @mathie guindon I tried True without "" still false.

Comment: @norie for now I'm doing it manually but this will be called by a workbook function before the workbook is saved ultimately. The checkbox purpose is to have the option to switch the notification on/off